# unable to upload images using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

In my rails app I have a customer form of two steps.In step one customer enters his details and logo and pdf and in the next step he selects a theme which he like.

my customers_controller

```
  def new
  if current_user.admin?
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.additional_fields.build
  else
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You dont have admin permissions'
  end
 end

 def edit
if current_user.admin?
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
else
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You dont have admin permissions'
end
end

  def theme_selector
 @customer_id = params[:customer_id]
 puts @customer_id
 end

 def create
 Rails.logger.debug "PARAMS:"
  params.each do |k,v|
  Rails.logger.debug "#{k}: #{v}"
end

if current_user.admin?
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html do
        redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.'
      end
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json do
        render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end
else
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You dont have admin permissions'
end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
   <%= form_for @customer, url: theme_selector_path,:method => :post,html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<%= @customer.id %>">
 <% if @customer.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2>
    <%= "#{pluralize(@customer.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this customer from being saved:" %>
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>
        <%= msg %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>
 <div class="form-group">
 <%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :address %>
<%= f.text_field :address, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :affiliate_id %>
<%= f.text_field :affiliate_id, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :logo, :class => 'control-label' %>
<div class="controls">
  <%= f.file_field :logo,accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg, image/jpg' %>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label>Upload File</label>
<%= f.file_field :file,accept: 'application/pdf' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<% f.fields_for :additional_fields do | ing | %>
  <%= ing.text_field :key, :size => 50 %>
  <%= ing.text_field :value, :size => 50 %>
<% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5">

    <span><%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn-addmore" %></span>
 <span><!--%= link_to 'Back', customers_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %-->    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">
    <%= link_to "next", theme_selector_path, class: "btn-update" %>

  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

I have a submit button at theme_selector.html.erb to create the customer.But I was getting an error "Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "#")" in customers controller create action.

development log:

```
 Processing by CustomersController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"customer"=>{"name"=>"test", "address"=>"test",   "affiliate_id"=>"test", "category"=>"", "domain"=>"test@web.com", "phone"=>"1111111111", "contact"=>"1214521", "email"=>"test@malibu.com", "comments"=>"none", "logo"=>"#  <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f3f4946c258>", "file"=>"#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f3f4946c208>"}}
  PARAMS:
 customer: #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007f3f442c0058>
 controller: customers
action: create
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
 Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "#   <ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f3f4946c258>"):

app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:47:in `create'
```

Thanks in Advance!

The step-1 of customer form contains customer details and step-2 contains theme selection.However I was able to upload and save the data in step-1 but I was getting the error while saving the data from step-1 and step-2 together at the theme_selector page .

customer.rb

```
    class Customer < ApplicationRecord


   has_attached_file  :logo
   validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

   has_attached_file  :file
    validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => "application/pdf" 

  end
```

Comment: can you post your model.rb code ?

Comment: @jith Thank you for the quick response, i have also posted customer.rd